# Updating maximum sum subinterval for an array when two elements are swapped

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

For a given array of real numbers, Kadane's dynamic programming algorithm can find the maximum sum subinterval in the array in linear time. However, suppose that we have done some preprocessing to obtain the optimal solution as well as any required auxilary information, and then we are given a transposition that swaps two elements in the array. Is there a scheme that will allow updating the optimal solution subinterval in sub-linear time, and allow future updates for subsequent transpositions as well? I'm looking for the preprocessing time and extra memory to be `o(N^2)` for an array of size `N`.

Comment: How much memory are you allowing yourself to store preprocessed information?

Comment: @Andrey It doesn't really matter, as long as the cost of preprocessing and doing N updates for an array of size N turns out to be faster than O(N^2). So the memory limit then would naturally be o(N^2) for an array of size N.

Comment: I'm thinking about the problem; meanwhile, I'll say that it might be easier to think about the question of, whether it is possible to solve the same problem but instead of a transposition of two elements, you just modify one of the elements in whatever way you like.  Obviously a solution to this problem implies a solution to yours.

Comment: I'm inclined to think that it may be impossible to find something that does everything you want in better than `O(N^2)` (for `N` updates in the list) in the worst case: the reason is that the more you pre-process, the more updates to the pre-proceeded data are required after a change in the list.  However I think I have an idea for something that should work pretty well in an "average case."  Will post soon, hopefully.

Comment: Actually, if such a solution wouldn't be useful to you, I won't bother, so let me know if you are interested in seeing something along those lines.

Comment: @Andrey Sure, average case is fine

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to pre-process the list to, in the average case, shrink the length of the list considerably.  It is also not too hard to update the pre-processed information given a change in one of the entries of the original list.

---

The idea of the pre-processing procedure is that certain collections of elements can be combined and logically treated as a single element.  For example, if there are two positive numbers next to each other in your list, as in

```
... -1 3 4 -2 ...
```

then you will never want to include 3 in your maximum subset sum unless you also include 4.  So, you can logically treat this portion of your list as

```
... -1 7 -2 ...
```

The same thing is true of adjacent negative numbers.  So, from now on, we can assume that the signs of the entries of our list alternate.

There are two other simplifications we'll need:

If there are two positive numbers with a negative number between them, and that negative number is smaller in magnitude than either of the two positive numbers, then you will never want to include either positive number in your maximum subset sum without including the other.  For example:

```
... 8 -2 4 ...
```

can be treated as

```
... 10 ...
```

This is because if we are including `4`, then we may as well include `-2 + 8 = 6` as well, similarly from the other side.

The other simplification is the analog for negative numbers.  If there are two negative numbers with a positive number between them, and the positive number is smaller in magnitude than either negative number, then we may treat the triple as a single number.  For example:

```
... -10 4 -12 ...
```

can be treated as

```
... -18 ...
```

It is harder to see why this is valid.  Let's say that our maximum subset sum does include one of these three numbers, say `-12`.  Then certainly it includes `4`, because that makes the subset sum bigger.  But it certainly must include `-10` as well, because if it doesn't, then we could cut `4 - 12 = -8` off of the end of the interval and make our subset sum bigger.  Intuitively, if this triple lives in the maximum subset sum interval, it is somewhere in the middle of the interval.

---

You need to apply these three simplifications recursively, until none produces a change in the list.  Potentially this can take a long time, but this can be shortened by tracking what tracts of the list have changed since the last iteration and only hitting those tracts with the repeated applications.

The advantage is that, after these modifications are applied, the maximum subset sum is *exactly the largest positive entry remaining in the (reduced) list*!  Here's a proof:

---

Suppose our list is reduced as per the above simplifications (meaning that applying any one of the three does nothing to it).  Suppose for the sake of contradiction that the maximum subset sum of this reduced list consists of more than a single entry.  So, let's represent the interval with the maximum subset sum as:

```
... a1 -b1 a2 -b2 ... a(n-1) b(n-1) an ...
```

Where the `ai` are positive, and the `bi` are negative.  (Note that neither end will be a negative number for obvious reasons.)

We will now produce our contradiction:

First, note that `a1 < b1`, because otherwise we could chop those two elements off that end and obtain a bigger subset sum.  Also `b1 > a2`, because our list is reduced, and if `b1 < a2` then `a1 -b1 a2` would have been collapsed to a single entry (since we already know that `b1 < a1`.

Next, note that `a2 > b2`.  This is because if `a2 < b2`, then this fact combined with `b1 < a2` would have caused `-b1 a2 -b2` to be collapsed to a single entry, as per the third simplification.

Applying these arguments over and over, we get the string of inequalities:

```
a1 > b1 > a2 > b2 > ... > a(n-1) > b(n-1) > an
```

but the last inequality is a contradiction, because if `b(n-1) > an`, then we can chop those two elements off of the interval and obtain a bigger subset sum.

(Note that I am ignoring the possibility that two adjacent `ai` and `bj` are equal.  You have to be a little careful with the signs to take care of this case but it works out fine, and the argument is easier to follow with strict inequalities.)

---

You need to keep the copy of the original list, and when the value of an element changes, apply the simplification steps "centered around" that element to avoid resimplifying more of the list than you have to.

Note that the more simplification you have to (really, are able to) do initially, the smaller the final list you end up with, saving you run-time later.  Probably the expected (aggregate) run-time of this is better than `O(N^2)` but I don't really want to think about it, this is a hairy algorithm to analyze.

It is probably fastest to keep a sorted list of the few highest maximum subset sum candidates, and to update that list selectively after new elements appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [square root decomposition](https://blog.anudeep2011.com/mos-algorithm/).

Just divide whole array into blocks of `sqrt(n)` size and compute answer for each block separately. When you update, you update only at most 2 blocks. Once you do it, you can apply Kadane's algorithm on block array (note, that there are at most `sqrt(n)` blocks). So you can get `O(sqrt(n))` time per update with linear preprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

In fact we can handle any sequence of updates in which one element of the array is modified, in O(log n) time per update and O(n) preprocessing time. A transposition is then just a sequence of 2 updates (modify one element then the other).

This is a generalization of the dynamic [range minimum query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_minimum_query) problem which is solved using a range tree. For our range tree, if a node is responsible for an interval I, instead of simply storing the smallest/largest value in I, we need to store 4 values:

- S(I), the sum of all elements in I
- L(I), the maximum (possibly empty) prefix sum of I
- R(I), the maximum (possibly empty) suffix sum of I
- M(I), the maximum (possibly empty) subinterval sum of I

When I is a single node, it is easy to compute S, L, R, and M.

Let's say I consists of two subintervals: I1 on the left, and I2 on the right. Clearly, S(I) = S(I1) + S(I2). To compute L(I), we observe that a prefix of I is either a prefix of I1, or the entirety of I1 concatenated with a prefix of I2. Therefore

L(I) = max(L(I1), S(I1) + L(I2))

Similarly

R(I) = max(R(I2), S(I2) + R(I1))

Finally, M(I) either falls entirely within I1, falls entirely within I2, or straddles the boundary between I1, or I2. In the last case, in other words, we combine a suffix of I1 with a prefix of I2, and obviously we want to choose the best possible suffix of I2 and best possible prefix of I2, therefore

M(I) = max(M(I1), M(I2), R(I1) + L(I2))

As you can see, it's necessary to keep all 4 values in order to calculate M-values as we climb up the tree. M alone for subintervals does not have enough information to calculate M for the combined interval.

There are O(n) nodes in the tree and it takes O(1) time to compute each one. When an update is performed, its O(log n) ancestors in the tree need to be updated and the M-value at the root (representing the whole array) can then be read off.

[SPOJ GSS3](https://www.spoj.com/problems/GSS3/) is a similar problem, where empty subarrays are not valid so a slight modification is required to the above scheme.